# Central limit theorem from which n works

Tags: r, self-study, central-limit-theorem

hello I have to write a program that for several distributions would check from which n the central limit theorem works.  I have absolutely no idea how to go about it.

---

honestly i'm a poor programmer and i don't know how to write code to display charts for different distributions.  I found this code but it probably only works for uniform distribution.  how to modify it to show me a histogram for the Poisson distribution?

https://youtu.be/66Uh6tw9IAE

Comment: I'm with you...  What does it mean if the CLT "works"?

Comment: It works for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: 1) Please use the self-study tag. 2) Please give the context in which you were assigned this homework problem. What are you studying? 3) What does it mean that the CLT works? In other words, what’s wrong with print(“Yep, CLT is true!”)?

Comment: I'd recommend to start with $n=1$ and go slow.  You can see how at each step your distribution starts to resemble normal more and more.  For instance, rectangular uniform at $n=1$ turns into triangular at $n=2$ and thereafter something smoother at $n=3$ (it's a piecewise quadratic function) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is not precise and the term *CLT works* is not accurate, I feel that the objective is to practically observe the effect of CLT (*limited by $n$*, the number of summands) for different distributions and different $n$, for you get a good intuition.

Pick some distributions, generate large number of samples, and see for which $n$ you get a histogram/or density close to normal. For example, uniform RV and $n=2$, your histogram will not look like normal, but for $n=20$ it'll pretty much. Here is a practical example for exponential RVs:

```
n = 50;
data = colSums(replicate(1e5,rexp(n)))
hist(data,100);
```

The decision for *likeness* is up to you. You can visually inspect just as above, or calculate KL divergence and set a threshold for closeness, observe Q-Q plots etc.

Comment: thank you, but how do you do it to make the distribution resemble normal or symmetrical with respect to 0? So what will the code look like when we subtract the expected value and divide it by the standard deviation?

Comment: @Piszczu before plotting the histogram, use `data = (data-mean(data))/sd(data)`

Comment: ok thank you, just tell me what values ​​should be taken in each of the timetables:

rbinom(n, size, prob)
rbeta(n, shape1, shape2)
rexp(n, rate = 1)
rgamma(n, shape, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate)
rnbinom(n, size, prob, mu)
rpois(n, lambda)
runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)

I understand that I have to change the value of n and look at the chart, but what about the other values ​​in the examples given? What should I choose?

Comment: I think trying different values for parameters and reporting if you see any behavioural changes is the best. There is no right or wrong choice unless inputs are valid.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I will sum up everything tomorrow and if I encounter any problems I will definitely write :)

Comment: I understand that this is the R language. Is it possible to generate the same code for C / C ++?

Comment: and why we use the function beginning r like rpois, rbinom.  How does this function work?

Comment: rpois creates poisson, rbinom creates binomial rvs. Those are functions defined in R. the prefix r stands for random. For cpp/c version I think it’s best to ask in SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering why the comments are all questioning the "works" phrase, it's because there is no official cutoff n where now CLT kicks in. It converges. That is, it gets closer and closer to normal as n gets bigger and bigger.

So you might demonstrate it by sampling from a non normal distribution with sample size small, repeat many times so you have lots of sample means, then plot the means. Then take a bigger sample size, repeat many times so you have lots of sample means, then plot the means.

Here is an example with generating 10000 samples of size 3, 10, and 300 from an exponential distribution lambda=2.You can see at first, it's definitely not normal, and then it sort of gets there, by 300 you can't tell the difference anymore. Indeed, it won't even take 300, but you can play with it yourself to see when you would call it 'normal'

```
x <- replicate(10000, {
  mm <- rexp(3,2)
  mean(mm)
})
hist(x, breaks=15, freq=F)

y <- replicate(10000, {
  mm <- rexp(10,2)
  mean(mm)
})
hist(y, breaks=15, freq=F)

z <- replicate(10000, {
  mm <- rexp(300,2)
  mean(mm)
})
hist(z, breaks=15, freq=F)
```

EDIT: as I type this I see Gunes has already typed an answer, but I started it so I might as well finish it.