# Illustrating the Central Limit Theorem: Simulate sums to approximate a Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

I have a hw assignment that I really don't understand and my professor isn't much help. I'm not looking for anyone to write me a code, but I'm looking for someone to explain to me the logic of this. Like what should I expect, what do each of the variables means and how do they relate to each other.

I want a thorough understanding before writing the code. Which will make it easier. I know I'm asking for a lot but its a pretty difficult class and it doesn't seem like anyone in my class understands either.

[image]

Comment: Your title seems to have little to do with the question... and a couple of other points.   First, you aren't generating a Gaussian, and second, you can't prove a theorem with a simulation.   Having written that, your professor is asking you to generate 10 realizations using the random number generator described and sum them.  Do this 1000 times, and plot a histogram of the results.

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there any advise or starting points you can give about how I would start something like this. I'm sorry for being so lost. I currently reading the text book, but he even said it wont be much help. I will be meeting with some classmates this week so we can share what we've been able to look up. we're all lost.

Comment: 1. Figure out how to generate a single number from the random number generator.  2.  Create an empty vector of length 1000.  3.  For j in 1:1000 ... generate 10 numbers from the RNG, sum them, and store the results in the $j^{th}$ element of the vector.  4. Plot a histogram of the results.

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/434257/central-limit-theorem-from-which-n-works/434259#434259) are some examples with means of an exponential distribution. Just figure out how to input rbinom instead of rexp in r. Also, read the comments they might help to explain matters.

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminaries.** There are several ways to get $X_i$'s from random numbers. One is shown below. [For others, see Note (4).]

```
set.seed(1234)   # for reproducibility 
r = runif(5);  r
[1] 0.1137034 0.6222994 0.6092747 0.6233794 0.8609154
y = (r > .5);  y
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   # logical vector
x = as.numeric(r > .5);  x
[1] 0 1 1 1 1                       # numeric vector
```

**Main part:** Put the $km = 10\,000$ Bernoulli (0 or 1) outcomes
into a matrix with $k$ rows and $m$ columns. Then sum the rows
to get 1000 approximately normal sums. Make a table or histogram of the
1000 `s`s. (This is much the same as in @jbowman's Comment.)

```
set.seed(2021)
m = 10;  k = 1000
r = runif(m*k)
x = as.numeric(r > .5)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=k)  # k rows; each a sample of m
s = rowSums(MAT)         # k sums of m 
head(s)
[1] 6 7 5 5 4 8          # first six of 1000
                         #   See Note (3)
summary(s);  sd(s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   4.000   5.000   5.033   6.000  10.000 
[1] 1.605144             # aprx sample SD = 1.581139

table(s)
s
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
 11  48 117 185 257 193 129  52   7   1 

hist(s, ylim=c(0,300), label=T)
```

[image]

---

Optionally, you might show the density function of
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 5, \sigma=\sqrt{10/4})$ superimposed on a histogram.

Actually, the sums in vector `s` are $\mathsf{Binom}(n=10, p=.5)$
with mean $np=10(.5) = 5$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}=$ $\sqrt{10(.5)(.5)} = \sqrt{10/4}.$

Also optionally, you might show dots matching the exact binomial probabilities. [Using parameter `prob=T` in the `hist` procedure makes the vertical scale so that PDFs can be superimposed on the histogram.]

```
cutp = (-1:10)+.5         # half-integer bin boundaries
hdr = "Simulated Sums of 10 BERN(.5) RVs"
hist(s, prob=T, br=cutp, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x, 5, sqrt(10/4)), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
 j = 0:10; pdf = dbinom(j, 10, .5)
 points(j, pdf, col="darkgreen")
```

[image]

*Notes:* (1) I hope this Answer helps you see the various steps required. I don't know how much R you know or whether you have covered Bernoulli, binomial, or normal distributions in your class. In your own work, please don't use anything
you don't totally understand. I may be available to answer questions on the
R code (or other details) later. Or try to use different approaches, based on what you already know.

(2) A normal density curve would fit the histogram more closely if we'd
used $k=10\,000$ instead of $k = 1000.$ (One peculiarity of
my particular simulation run, with `set.seed(2021)`, is that none of the $k$ sums was $0.)$

(3) Here are the first six rows (out of 1000) of `MAT`:

```
head(MAT)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1     0
[2,]    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1     1
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    1     0
[4,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
[5,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1     0
[6,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     0
```

(4) In R, `x = rbinom(5, 1, .5)` would give a theoretically equivalent string of 0's and 1's as shown in the 'preliminary' section. (See @HuyPham's Comment.)
With the same seed (`1234`), the result may differ because of the way `rbinom` is programmed to use random numbers.

You could also get $X_i$'s from uniform random numbers by using `if` statements.